# Importing csv file to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, csv

I'm trying to import a csv file to a table in sql server 2005 with the wizard.
but when i import the file is always give me this errors :

> Executing (Error) Messages Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data
>   conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Column 15" returned
>   status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more
>   characters had no match in the target code page.".  (SQL Server Import
>   and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "output column "Column 15"
>   (70)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row
>   disposition on "output column "Column 15" (70)" specifies failure on
>   truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the
>   specified component.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing
>   file "C:\PEP_ENTITIES_71.csv" on data row 1.  (SQL Server Import and
>   Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source
>   - PEP_ENTITIES_71_csv" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called
>   PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
>   component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

What i'm doing wrong? This file was a export from a query, then i delete all records and try to import.

Comment: Are you importing into an existing table?  What is the table structure?

Comment: Check the data type for `Column 15`.one possible reason for the above error can be due to size of the Column which is causing the truncation of data .Try increasing the size of the column for csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flat file import task will default lengths to `VARCHAR(50)`. You need to go to the Advanced property of the flat file connection page and change the length manually to match the destination table. There should also be an option to Suggest Types which may match the metadata that you're using, but it does a sampling of rows from the file so it may not be as accurate as just setting types manually.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you're trying to import data from the CSV which is too large for the field you're importing it in to. Perhaps you need to increase the size of your fields in your SQL table?

Have you tried to import a single, very small line of data from the CSV to see if that works? If it does, excessively large data somewhere in the rest of the sheet may be the problem.